# Simple IIF statement to determine a sum

Tags: reporting-services, ssrs-2008

I am a rookie to SSRS and am having difficulty obtaining a Sum.

I want the cell to Sum the distinct values  of "UnitNumber" which is what the report is using to generate each row of my table. The reasoning behind this is that behind the complex report, Unit numbers are distinct and provide me with distinct SqFt Values. For example:

```
Unit #   | Sqft|

Unit 001 | 472 |

Unit 002 | 600 |

Unit 004 | 1203|
```

The below does not work:

```
Sum(IIF(Fields!Unitnumber.Value,1,Fields!SqFt.Value)
```

I either get "Contains an error: cannot be converted to String" or, #Error in the cell. I cannot solely use Sum(SqFt) because it dumps an aggregate of the whole dataset query (every single row summed up)  Any ideas?

Comment: your sum condition is wrong. check iif block.

Comment: Why don't you create a group by `UnitNumber`? just use `sum(Fields!Sqft.Value,"UnitNumberGroup")`. Replace `UnitNumberGroup`by the actual group name.

Answer (score 0):

It seems that your `IIF` missing main condition. It can be something like below or do as per your requirement.

```
Sum(IIF(Fields!Unitnumber.Value=1,1,Fields!SqFt.Value)
```

Also, I would suggest you to make your expression like below,

```
=SUM(IIF(Fields!Unitnumber.Value = 'putyourcondition', Fields!SqFt.Value, 0))
```

Comment: I tried both solutions with no luck.

@alejandro_zuelta sum(Fields!Sqft.Value,"UnitNumber1") gives me an aggregate error and  the second Sum(IIF result produces an #error even when changed to CDEC(SUM(IIF 

I was hoping this would distinctivly tell the report to chose the UnitNumbers and sum the associated SqFt values but the only results I am getting are large aggregate of the query (all rows) instead of distinct rows. Any idea why this is?